# Assigning a property to oozie workflow not in job.properties file but in workflow.xml itself and use it further

Tags: dynamic, properties, workflow, oozie

I have a oozie workflow wchich consists of a sub-workflow. My main workflow takes three sqoop job names at a time in fork. Then it has to pass those names to the subworkflow. In main workflow there are three shell actions which receive values of job names in three respective variables(${job1},${job2},${job3}) . But my sub-workflow is common for all three shell actions. I want to assign the value of ${job1} to ${job}. Where to create the property ${job} and how to transfer the value of ${job1} to ${job}???? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Use a java action in between along with **capture-output** so that you can do whatever assignment or name change logic there. 
Java will accept job1 and will output job=job1 using capture-output which in turn you may pass to sub-workflows.